# Wordpress CPT pagination error 1st and 2nd page are fine but not the ones after

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I've been trying this for days at this point and I can not get it to work..
I am trying to have a posts page in wordpress with all my posts AND my CPTs. I am doing this by making a post loop with a custom query in `index.php` which prints fine. Then I try to make it paginate through the `paginate_links()` function, But I get a `404` error when clicking on it. Which is a common issue. The kicker is that it doesn't do it on the first nor the second page, it only does it on page three and up. An even stranger thing with this code is that it reacts differently on my work computer than on my home computer (they are different local servers with different amount of posts in each post type. I'm guessing that's why they work differently) Anyways on my work computer the second page also gives me an error.

I have already changed my reading settings to 1 post at most per page. I don't know what else I can be doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged') ) ? get_query_var( 'paged') : 1;

// custom post loop
$arg_custom_post_loop = array(
    'post_type' => array('post', 'ljm_utstallningar', 'ljm_event', 'ljm_arkiv', 'ljm_bildarkiv', 'ljm_film', 'ljm_pag'), 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
);

$ljm_custom_post_loop = new WP_Query($arg_custom_post_loop);

$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $ljm_custom_post_loop;

if ($ljm_custom_post_loop->have_posts()) {
    while ($ljm_custom_post_loop->have_posts()) {
        $ljm_custom_post_loop->the_post();
        get_template_part('template/default-content-thumbnail', get_post_type());
    }
    echo paginate_links();

}
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp_query;
?>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: The `paginate_links` function works with the global WQ_Query object, you are making your own query here. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops

Comment: @CBroe Am I not already doing that? I rewrote my code several times and even copied pasted from the example and it didn't work.. I am very confused

Comment: But you are calling `paginate_links` with only the default parameters, meaning it will grab the `total` from the main query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it to work with this code:

```
<?php 
// fixing pagination for custom loop

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on') {
    // code...
}else{
    $url= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url = parse_url($url);
}

$current_page = explode('/', $url['query']);
$current_page = end($current_page);
 if (!is_numeric($current_page)) {
    $current_page = 1;
 }

// custom post loop
$arg_custom_post_loop = array(
    'post_type' => array('post', 'ljm_utstallningar', 'ljm_event', 'ljm_arkiv', 'ljm_bildarkiv', 'ljm_film', 'ljm_pag'), 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $current_page,
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
);

$ljm_custom_post_loop = new WP_Query($arg_custom_post_loop);

$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $ljm_custom_post_loop;

if ($ljm_custom_post_loop->have_posts()) {
    while ($ljm_custom_post_loop->have_posts()) {
        $ljm_custom_post_loop->the_post();
        get_template_part('template/default-content-thumbnail', get_post_type());
    }

    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
        'format' => '/page/%#%',
        'current' => $current_page,
        'total' => $ljm_custom_post_loop->max_num_pages,
    ));
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp_query;
?>
```

Its not pretty but it works, I throw the hole `paginate_links()` default action out the window and just use it to print the page number in the url. Then I retrieve the number from the url and push it in the `paged` and `current` arguments.

Thanks @CBroe for the push to understand why my first code didn't work :)